# PHP Mysql database fields

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm in development of a movie statistics website and i'm trying to figure out what the best way to go is for the database.

The website is about movies. But each movie will have different fields. I need help to figure out the best way to store this data.

For example. I have one table called "movies". This will have all the general information. But for some movies, I want them to have their own fields with other information.

I could create a table for each movie, but after the amount of movies build up, its going to make the database look very messy and unorganised, which I don't want. I could then build placeholder fields for the "movies" table, but I may need one or two, or I may need 10 or 20 extra fields.

Would anyone be able to recommend what way I should approach this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to handle your situation is to create a movie attributes table, where every record in that table represents a single attribue for a certain movie.  A table definition like the following might make sense:

```
CREATE TABLE movie_attribute (
    movie_attr_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    movie_id NOT NULL 
    attr_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    attr_value VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY fk_movie(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id)
)
```

Using this design, any number of attributes can be added for a given movie without requiring a big design change.  Database tables were designed to comfortably grow row-wise, not column-wise.

Comment: The surrogate is surely redundant. A satisfactory PK can be formed on entity and attribute.

Comment: This would assume that every key, value pair attribute for a given movie is distinct which might not always he true, especially if these attributes were coming from an uncontrolled outside source.

Comment: So there's no natural key here?

Comment: @Strawberry Maybe there is, maybe not, the crux of my answer is to treat the movie attributes as key/value pairs rather than adding new columns or, worse yet, creating new movie tables.  Let the OP ask if further clarification needed.

Comment: Fair enough....